# Regarding desktop share concept

Tags: c#, desktop, share

i have developed two a small apps by which i can send desktop picture with mouse position to another apps. another apps receiving the picture and shows those picture on picture box.

1) so i want to know that how could i send my all mouse keys and keyboard activity in very structure way to another apps which is sending picture.

2) when another apps will receive my mouse & keyboard activity then they will fire properly.

so please tell me how could i send mouse & keyboard activity very structure way and another things is to know that how could programmatically fire those mouse & keyboard activity on another machine. here i am developing this apps with c#. so please give me the concept as a result i can code it in c#. thanks.

Comment: It's called 'remote desktop' .

Comment: I agree with Henk, why are you reinventing the wheel?  Is this just a learning exercise?

Comment: I disagree. The fact that someone else already made it should not lead to the conclusion that it is not worth trying! Why 3-years old is drawing a poor picture? da Vinci already painted Mona Lisa... See my point?

Answer (score 1):

Sending a picture (or any data) over a network is relatively easy.

Intercepting and re-creating Mouse and Keybord actions is entirely different. It will involve a lot of lowlevel hooking into Windows, no ready-to-use libraries.

You will have to be proficient in Interop and Marshaling, and maybe C# (.NET) just isn't the best tool for this job.